# How to create Guid in @Html.checkboxfor

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

First i have model

```
public class Sub_C2B 
{
    public string OrderID_Cut { get; set; } }
```

and in view page i create  dropdownlist when choose yes i'll create id for OrderID_Cut

```
<div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Subc2bs.OrderID_Cut, new SelectList(new List<Object>{
                   new { value = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() , text = "Yes"  },
                   new { value = "-" , text = "No" }}, "value", "text", Model.Subc2bs.OrderID_Cut))
    </div>
```

if i want to use checkboxfor replace dropdownlist. 
What should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a `bool` for `OrderID_Cut` is more appropriate for your use case since it's either yes or no. As follows:

```
public class Sub_C2B 
{
    public bool OrderID_Cut { get; set; } 

    //...more properties here
}
```

Then In your view:

```
<div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.OrderID_Cut)
</div>
```

And checking whether the value is yes or not (true or false) when posted back:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyControllerAction(Sub_C2B model)
{
    if(model.OrderID_Cut)
    {
         //value is true, act as needed
    }
}
```